# Potential, mass and direction of force due to that mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator

In the derivative of a potential (which is in the shape of a parabola), is a slope and it has a mass $m$ in the positive slope. Why does the mass tend to exert force in the negative slop direction?

[image]

Comment: Please define the y-axis.

Comment: and why do you think mass is the one who exerts force? Mass is just a measurement of body's inertia, If I understand your doubt correctly, You seem to be confused about why is there an extra negative sign in relation between force and gradient of potential, this article explains it pretty well http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pegrav.html

Comment: I am confused, as this is an unexplored territory. Exactly. I wanted to know why the direction of the force is negative. I think the y-axis must be k space

Answer (score 0):

I think that the vertical axis here should be potential energy $U(x)$ and the horizontal axis is $x$.  The $x$ component of the associated conservative force is then $F_x(x) = - \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d} x} U(x)$.  So for $U(x) = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$, as shown, the $x$-component of the force is $F_x = -kx$. This represents one-dimensional motion under a conservative force. When the position is positive the force component is negative (the force vector points in the negative $x$ direction).

The drawing of a vector "down the slope" is just to use the analogy of a ball in a parabolic-shaped bowl.  For one-dimensional motion the force vector points only in the  $\pm x$ direction.  However, one could take the bowl literally and derive a one dimensional potential as a function of position along the bowl.  This would involve the construction of a 1D conservative force from the component of the (conservative) gravitational force along the bowl surface. In that case one could think of that force literally pointing along the bowl surface.